# network related commands suddenly stopped working

Tags: linux-networking, debian-stretch

Debian GNU/Linux 9.12 (stretch) Release: 9.12

Today I realized that a few network related commands suddenly stopped working.
For example: pin, host, iptables, dig and so on, they don't work anymore.

Here's the output of route -n, for example

```
root@host5:~# route -n
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.104.153 0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 ens160
192.168.104.152 0.0.0.0         255.255.255.248 U     0      0        0 ens160
root@host5:~# ping 192.168.104.153
PING 192.168.104.153 (192.168.104.153) 56(84) bytes of data.
^C
--- 192.168.104.153 ping statistics ---
7 packets transmitted, 0 received, 100% packet loss, time 6127ms
```

ifconfig command output

```
root@fhost5:~# ifconfig
ens160: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.104.156  netmask 255.255.255.248  broadcast 192.168.104.159
        inet6 fe80::250:56ff:fe88:3d72  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 00:50:56:88:3d:72  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 4581  bytes 910358 (889.0 KiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 13  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 4562  bytes 417363 (407.5 KiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0


host IP address: 192.168.104.156
network segment: 192.168.104.152/29
```

Actually I cannot ping the gateway.
But from another host on the same network segment, **the gateway is reachable**

I was thinking that the issue is somewhat related to the system ...I mean a local issue
All the network commands seem to be stuck
You know I run iptables and nothing happens, the same with host ..etc

```
root@host5:~# host google.com
^Croot@host5:~#
```

Unfortunately I got nowhere.

Any help will be highly appreciated

Comment: does this also happen when you work with IP-Adresses instead of hostnames. for example: does #> ping 8.8.8.8 and #> ping 192.168.104.156 work?

Comment: thanks actually it doesn't work in both cases

Comment: but the network connections of this machine is still working? you connected to it via ssh? you can ping it from another machine?

Comment: dmesg or other system logs don't show any clues? Always look there when system starts behaving very strange.

Comment: I can access the machine through ssh...dmesg shows many things like [   10.892307] EXT4-fs (sda1): mounting ext2 file system using the ext4 subsystem
[   10.928221] EXT4-fs (sda1): mounted filesystem without journal. Opts: (null)
[   20.194301] ip6_tables: (C) 2000-2006 Netfilter Core Team
[   20.424976] vmxnet3 0000:03:00.0 ens160: intr type 3, mode 0, 5 vectors allocated
[   20.426346] vmxnet3 0000:03:00.0 ens160: NIC Link is Up 10000 Mbps
what should I look for.. another important thing I cannot ping it from another host

Comment: also dmesg shows: 0.368068] pci 0000:00:17.6: BAR 13: failed to assign [io  size 0x1000] 42 messages like this

Comment: Is anyone willing to help me? Is something related to the kernel?

Comment: related to Nikitas suggestion to check the `dmesg` output: run one of the network commands that hang, then check with `dmesg` if there are new kernel log messages.
you could also try to install "strace" (`apt install strace` on debian or ubuntu machines) and run something link `strace ping 8.8.8.8` and check if this gives you a clue what the program was trying to do, the moment it started to hang.
have you checked if the non-working binaries or other binaries have been changed recently?
`ls -l \`which ping\``
`dpkg --verify`
``

Comment: thanks Marc...I cannot ping any host..every network related command just hangs...other tools seem to be working (I mean I can start them i though they run very slowly...) what about a kernel roll back? do you think that would be a good idea?